# Payara Glassfish Server Deployment: Error when listing directory

Tags: java, web, glassfish, payara, java-ee-8

I'm facing an issue in Glassfish server with my Java EE project. Whenever I start coding, I will start my local Glassfish server and deploy my Java EE project to the server. After the deployment is completed, I will start coding. Every time I added or modified the project source code, the project will redeploy. When the project is redeploying, the server log will show this error (Refer to the following screenshot).

```
  keepstate options resolved to true, saving appId 106861107804831744 for application javaProject.|#]
  keepstate options resolved to true, saving appId 106861107804831744 for application javaProject.|#]
  Persistent Timers will not be destroyed since keepstate is true for application javaProject|#]
  Persistent Timers will not be destroyed since keepstate is true for application javaProject|#]
  Error when listing directory
 Error when listing directory
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\ejb\javaProject
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.<init>(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:518)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
    at java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3451)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.DirWatcher$ParentWatcher.register(DirWatcher.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.DirWatcher.registerInFilesystem(DirWatcher.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.DirWatcher.register(DirWatcher.java:87)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader$URLEntry.init(ASURLClassLoader.java:950)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader$URLEntry.<init>(ASURLClassLoader.java:935)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.appendURL(ASURLClassLoader.java:266)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.addURL(ASURLClassLoader.java:249)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarHandler.getClassLoader(EarHandler.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createDeploymentClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:229)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:538)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:554)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:553)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:584)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:576)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1878)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1754)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:554)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:553)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:584)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:576)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1878)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1754)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This error doesn't happen every time, sometimes the redeployment is perfectly work without this error. Also, although the error is exist, I still able to test my code (browser able to load the updated version).

I have checked the path (refer in the screenshot above) and make sure it's accessible from every windows users, but the issue still exists. I also did some research online about my problem, none of the solution is work for my situation. In this case, I decide to ignore the error, proceed to code. But when this error happens multiple times, a new error will be introduced (refer to the following screen).

```
javax.servlet.servletexception: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I also do some research about the second error and I already increase my server JVM heap size to 3500. But both issues still remain unsolved (That's why I am here to seek for solution).

Anyone here have any solution for my issue? (Do let me know if u need any extra info to understand my problem).

My setup:

1. JDK & JRE: 1.8.0_201
2. Payara Glassfish Server 5.194

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related with "Deploy on save" setting. Personally I use this setting only when I'm working with xhtml, sometimes with cdi beans, but switch it off when coding ejb